# How to get 24 hours before records from mongodb with python.?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a requirement to delete records from my mongodb collection 24 hours before from present time.i have records like

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53993f67ccbc960c7d05b74d"),
"userName" : "krishna",
"countryCode" : "91",
"countryName" : "India",
"mobileNumber" : "99143xxxxx",
"name" : "Krishna",
"password" : "aXRvbkAxMjM=",
"registeredOn" : ISODate("2014-06-12T05:49:27.970Z"),

}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53993f67ccbc960c7d05b74e"),
"userName" : "mulagala",
"countryCode" : "91",
"countryName" : "India",
"mobileNumber" : "99122xxxxx",
"name" : "Krishna",
"password" : "aXRvbkAxMjM=",
"registeredOn" : ISODate("2014-06-16T05:49:27.970Z"),

}
```

Now i want to remove a record that is registered 24 hours before from present time.How to delete it from python.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you made any attempt to write code for this yourself?

Comment: @Ffisegydd, Yes i am calling a thread for every 10 minuits for checking, But i am not sure how to check the condition for checking 24 hours time

Comment: Can you provide what code you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can approach this with a query and run it periodically:

```
collection.remove({ 
    'registeredOn': { '$lte': datetime.now() - timedelta( hours=24 ) }
})
```

Or you could look at [TTL Indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/). The mongodb server periodically checks these every few minutes without coding anything additional:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { "registeredOn": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 86400 } )
```

So if you can make that work for you and you do not need any manual control it is probably a good approach for your application.